Explaining "saying vs. showing" in Wittgenstein's Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus
When thinking about the distinction between saying and showing in Ludwig Wittgenstein's Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus, I'm reminded of the "dictionary game" where you attempt to define a word by using other words ... and then those words, themselves, require definitions (sometimes circular), until you reach a point when you can only point to the sky and say "That's blue", or tell a joke and say "That's funny", etc.
The meanings of these words still exists. However, the meaning may transcend language - language can only point the way to what is essentially a private experience (albeit one we all share).
Is this a correct interpretation of saying vs. showing at the heart of Wittgenstein's Tractatus?

See also this post.

For the Tractatus, the context is Russell's solution to the paradox by way of the hierarchy of types: the "grammer" of types must be defined outside them, but if only the typed language is meaningful, its grammer cannot be said but only shown.

The distinction is a bit cryptic and interpreters had hard time reconciling Wittgenstein's various uses of it in the Tractatus and elsewhere, see Decauwert, Saying and Showing. But few think that it has to do with ostensive definitions (he explicitly criticizes ostensive view of language) or privacy of experiences (they are public if shared, not private). It has more to do with representation being able to say what it represents but not how it represents it. So a sentence cannot say its logical form, for instance, only show it.

The Tractarian distinction between showing and saying is grounded in the so-called thesis of the ineffability of semantics:

3.263. The meanings of primitive signs can be explained by means of elucidations. Elucidations are propositions that contain the primitive signs. So they can only be understood if the meanings of those signs are already known.


4.12. Propositions can represent the whole of reality, but they cannot represent what they must have in common with reality in order to be able to represent it—logical form. In order to be able to represent logical form, we should have to be able to station ourselves with propositions somewhere outside logic, that is to say outside the world.

We have objects, structure (the arrangement of objects in states of affairs), and form (the limit of the possible arrangement of objects in states of affairs): propositions represent facts because they have the same structure.
Propositions are picture of reality. A picture depicts a state of affairs in virtue of the way its elements are assembled in a structure. Form is what a picture has in common with what it depicts; it is that in virtue of which the organization of picture's elements constitutes a representation of a possible state of affairs.
But, "A picture cannot, however, place itself outside its representational form [2.174]."
See also Russell's Introducion:

The essential business of language is to assert or deny facts. [...] In order that a certain sentence should assert a certain
fact there must, however the language may be constructed, be something in common between the structure of the sentence and the structure of the fact. [...] That which has to be in common between the sentence and the fact cannot, so he contends, be itself in turn said in language. It can, in his phraseology, only be shown, not said, for whatever we may say will still need to have the same structure.

To understand this point of view, it is relevant also W's critique to Principia's Theory of Types: in order to avoid paradoxes the logical perfect language must be organized into a hierarchy.
But the "grammer" of types must be defined outside the hierarchy, with the apparent paradox that, if only the typed language is meaningful, its grammer cannot be expressed.
The meaning of signs are the rules to use them (and this thesis is fundamental also for the "second Wittgenstein"): "From this observation we turn to Russell’s ‘theory of types’. It can be seen that Russell must be wrong, because he had to mention the meaning of signs when establishing the rules for them [3.331]."
And "When something falls under a formal concept as one of its objects, this cannot be expressed by means of a proposition. Instead it is shown in the very sign for this object [4.126]."
In conclusion: your suggested analogy with the "dictionary game" is fine.
Natural language is circular, while a regimented language must avoid circularity to prevent paradoxes and contradicitons: see the Liar as well as Tarski's Truth Definition: Object language and metalanguage.

Thank you! Something else that comes to mind when discussing the ineffability of semantics are questions such as "What is a hand?" Is an object still a hand if you remove a finger? Or two, or three? Replace the hand with a hook? (Also see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_know_it_when_I_see_it)
Or (seemingly) deep philosophical questions like "What is the meaning of life?" which are grammatically correct but not reflective of reality. I think Wittgenstein would say "What is the meaning of life?" is a nonsensical question.

Self-referential language and meaning lying outside of a language or logic system has some similarities with Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, though I don't know if Gödel or Wittgenstein were inspired by the other.

@RobertF - W's Tractatus was first published in German in 1921 (and written earlier) while Gödel's result dates 1931. But W later made some controversial comments about the result.
